# htaccess redirect domain by checking languages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've a website with 3 languages - German (de), French (fr) and Italian (it). I've 2 domains; one is pointed to German and another one to French and Italian.

```
www.language1.com => de
www.language2.com/fr => fr
www.language2.com/it => it
```

Now the redirections are working fine. But if I access the url www.language2.com directly without any language (/fr/ or /it/) parameter, I want to redirect that to www.language2.com/it/. But if I access www.language2.com/fr, it should not redirect.

So, how can I check exactly the url is www.language2.com (without any language) and redirect to /it/ using htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried different methods and none of them was working. Can you show me sample code with the above example? Thank you

Comment: Sorry but this is not *write code for me* service. Once you try something and it doesn't work then surely we can help.